# Test multidimensional array with Laravel and Pest

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, unit-testing, multidimensional-array

I have a little problem when I want to test an array in my unit test.

I want to test both structure and type of keys, but I don't know how to process it (I tried, I promise!).

Here is the json input:

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "domains_id": 1,
            "sub": "",
            "type": "",
            "ip_or_fqdn": "",
            "created_at": "2022-05-14T08:30:18.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-05-14T08:30:18.000000Z"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Domain retrieved successfully."
}
```

And there is, for the moment, the test:

```php
it('fetch zone entries [GET] with json response and check response type', function () {

    TestCase::initDatabase();

    Passport::actingAs(
        User::factory()->make()
    );

    $response = $this->withHeaders([
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ])
        ->json('GET', '/api/zone')
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJson(function (AssertableJson $json) {
            $json->has('success')
                 ->whereType('success', 'boolean')
                 ->has('data')
                 ->whereType('data', 'array')
                 ->has('message')
                 ->whereType('message', 'string');
    });

    TestCase::resetDatabase();
});
```

I want to test the "data" array keys/values with this process and, of course, in this Closure; but is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use dot notation, for instance

```
->assertJson(fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
    $json->has('data.id')
        ->where('data.id', 1)
        ->missing('data.x')
    );
```

Comment: I forgot to precise the data array is a indexed array, so do I have to use the "has" method like this? $json->has('data.0.id') or a joker notation like $json->has('data.*.id')?

Comment: Yes. Don't think you can use the joker like that. Maybe you want to take a look at assertJsonStructure: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-tests#assert-json-structure

Answer (score 2):

Finally, with @ajthinking tips, here is the final test and it works, thank you very much!

```php
it('fetch zone entries [GET] with json response and check response type', function () {

    TestCase::initDatabase();

    Passport::actingAs(
        User::factory()->make()
    );

    $response = $this->withHeaders([
        'Accept' => 'application/json'
    ])
        ->json('GET', '/api/zone')
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJson(function (AssertableJson $json) {
            $json->has('success')
                 ->whereType('success', 'boolean')
                 ->has('data')
                 ->whereType('data', 'array')
                 ->has('data.0')
                 ->has('data.0')
                    ->has('data.0.id')
                    ->has('data.0.sub')
                    ->has('data.0.type')
                    ->has('data.0.ip_or_fqdn')
                    ->has('data.0.created_at')
                    ->has('data.0.updated_at')
                    ->whereType('data.0.id', 'integer')
                    ->whereType('data.0.sub', 'string')
                    ->whereType('data.0.type', 'string')
                    ->whereType('data.0.ip_or_fqdn', 'string')
                    ->whereType('data.0.created_at', 'string')
                    ->whereType('data.0.updated_at', 'string')
                 ->has('message')
                 ->whereType('message', 'string');
    });

    TestCase::resetDatabase();
});
```

I'll improve this test with an assertJsonStructure() in the future to test base structure and test types in assertJson() closure.

EDIT:

Here is the test with assertJsonStructure() method, and it works fine:

```php
it('fetch zone entries [GET] with json response and check response type', function () {

    TestCase::initDatabase();

    Passport::actingAs(
        User::factory()->make()
    );

    $response = $this->withHeaders([
        'Accept' => 'application/json'
    ])
        ->json('GET', '/api/zone')
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJsonStructure([
            'success',
            'data' => [
                '*' => [
                    'id',
                    'sub',
                    'type',
                    'ip_or_fqdn',
                    'created_at',
                    'updated_at'
                ]
                ],
            'message'
        ])
        ->assertJson(function (AssertableJson $json) {
            $json->whereType('success', 'boolean')
                 ->whereType('data', 'array')
                 ->whereType('data.0.id', 'integer')
                 ->whereType('data.0.sub', 'string')
                 ->whereType('data.0.type', 'string')
                 ->whereType('data.0.ip_or_fqdn', 'string')
                 ->whereType('data.0.created_at', 'string')
                 ->whereType('data.0.updated_at', 'string')
                 ->whereType('message', 'string');
    });

    TestCase::resetDatabase();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use macro, e.g. for structure testing

```php
TestResponse::macro('assertJsonCollectionStructure', 
    fn (array $structure) =>
        $this->assertJsonStructure([
           'success,
           'data' => [$structure], 
           'message',
        ])
);
```

and than use it

```php
->assertJsonCollectionStructure([
    'id',
    'domains_id',
    // ...
])
```